# getOrder() doesn't return Mage_Sales_Model_Order when debugging

Tags: database, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I try to `var_dump($order)` but it gives me :

```
object(Varien_Object)#290 (7) { ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

My `class PaketId_Shipping_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Shipment_View_Shipping extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Shipment {`

```
protected $order;

public function getOrder() {
    if (is_null($this->order)) {
        if (Mage::registry('current_order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('order')) {
            $order = Mage::registry('order');
        }
        else {
            $order = new Varien_Object();
        }
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    return $this->order;
}
```

My phtml file :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('PaketId_Shipping');?>
<h1>Test custom block</h1>
<?php $order = $this->getOrder()?>
<?php var_dump($order);?>
<?php $shippings = Mage::getModel('paketid_shipping/result')->getCollection()->addOrderFilter($order) ?>
<?php echo "<pre>";?>
<?php var_dump($shippings);?>
<?php echo "</pre>" ;?>
```

My variable `$order` in phtml file somehow doesn't call the `$order` in block file, or I have been misunderstanding about this? Because, when i try to `var_dump($order)` in other phtml, it returns `object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order)#276...`

I tried changing `$this-getOrder()` into `Mage::registry('current_order')` but it gives me `NULL`. What did I do wrong?

My collection:

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{

protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result');
}
public function addOrderFilter($order)
{
    if ($order instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $order = (int) $order->getId();
    }
    if (!is_array($order)) {
        $order = array($order);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.order_id IN (?)", $order);

    return $this;
}
protected function _toOptionArray($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='booking_code', $additional=array())
{
    return parent::_toOptionArray($valueField, $labelField, $additional);
}
protected function _toOptionHash($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='booking_code')
{
    return parent::_toOptionHash($valueField, $labelField);
}
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    return $countSelect;
}
```

My resource :

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Resource_Result extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result', 'entity_id');
}
```

My result :

```
class PaketId_Shipping_Model_Result extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
const ENTITY    = 'paketid_shipping_result';
const CACHE_TAG = 'paketid_shipping_result';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'paketid_shipping_result';
protected $_eventObject = 'paketid_shipping_result';
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('paketid_shipping/result');
}
```

Admin layout xml:

```
<layout version="1.0">
<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="paketid_shipping/adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view_shipping" name="paketid_shipping.order.view.shipping.block" template="paketid/shipping.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please extend your module class from Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Shipment or from Mage_Sales_Block_Order_View call and check it hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but which file ? I mean, extends from Mage_Sales_Block_Order_View change into what?

Comment: I just replaced Mage_Core_Block_Template to Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Shipment

Comment: it gives me ` Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Helper\Data.php on line 119`

Comment: remove get order function because this was already existed in Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Shipment

Comment: can you please let me know are you using your module on sales order view page?

Comment: in sales_order_shipment_view. Because I want to show queries on that page. Like, `select * from mytable where order_id=$order` I need to get `current_order` and use its `order_id` to show some records on mytable. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I have `paketid_booking_result` table (its the actual table name from an extension), it consists of `entity_id | order_id | booking_id | booking_code | email | name | phone | reference_code` . I need to show those fields in shipment_view. I have added my models.

Comment: try this function
public function addOrderFilter($order)
{
    if ($order) {
        $order_id= (int) $order->getId();
    }
    if (!is_array($order)) {
        $order = array($order);
    }

    $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.order_id IN (?)",$order_id);

    return $this;
}

Comment: please print order in phtml and let me know

Comment: still the same result, `object(Varien_Object)#290 (7) { ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { }`

Comment: try to replace Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Shipment with Mage_Sales_Block_Order_View
and also print_r($order->getData());

Comment: `Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Helper\Data.php on line 119`

Comment: I changed it to `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and added getData() but it returns `array(0)`

Comment: actually order registry has been empty so it is return noting